# About Articulate in HTML5, and information left by a course

Tags: xml, output, scorm1.2, articulate

I'm new to Articulate, and I need your help. I have an Articulate course exported to HTML5 format. This course is not integrated inside any LMS system, it's just left in a folder of a web server. I want to pass this course, and see where the final result in scorm format is left, so I can download it and see the results. My question is: where is this information saved by Articulate?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The course will try to save this data either to an LMS using SCORM or an LRS using Tin Can depending on how you have it configured. If you don't configure the course with any tracking and/or don't have an LMS or LRS then this data is not saved anywhere.